# login failed when tyring to log into paypal account from android sdk example with sandbox environment

Tags: android, authentication, paypal, account

I want to test paypal in my android app
to do that I have followed all steps of docs of paypal

the sdk example works well in sandbox envirement with credit card payment

but when I test  payment with paypal,I canno't arrive to log in

always, I have this message

> login failed : invalid login information please try again

knowing that I have entered the right email and passwod and not the account to which the payment will be send

but only one thing, the paypal account is only for testing and not linked to a credit card

do you have any idea

Answer (score 1):

The PayPal developer site lets you create new sandbox accounts.  Navigate to [Applications > Sandbox accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts) to add more accounts.